# Yii require_once fail, can't run demo project

Tags: php, yii

Interestingly I have another version of yii running and that runs with out error but that one does not have gii. I installed the latest and when I build a demo project, it give me this error. I think it is related to permission. I tried different solution but could not make it work.

I am using XAMMP on Mac OS Lion

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required '/Users/tstuser/Sites/yii2/demo2/../framework/yii.php'
>   (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear')
>   in /Users/tstuser/Sites/yii2/demo2/index.php on line 13

Trying changing the directory permission but to no avail.

Comment: you may need to change the parent permissions -- generally I've found it's easier to create a web/htdocs folder outside the Users directory and you'll have less permissions problems. If you want to keep it where it is, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001881/correct-owner-group-permissions-for-apache-2-site-files-folders-under-mac-os-x-1 (not sure if things are different on Lion tho).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Debian Linux server. I fixed this by installing php-pear.

Please see [this](http://www.popoleodesigns.com/blog/installing-pear-on-mac-os-x-leopard-xampp/) guide for installing pear on xampp and Mac OS.

Hope this helps