# Error when saving in Web Storm (Permission Denied)

Tags: xampp, save, permission-denied, webstorm

When I click save in Web Storm I get the following Error:

```
Could not save project:
java.io.FileNotFoundException:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/[myFileName]/.idea/workspace.xml~ (Permission denied)
```

As far as I can tell my changes are being saved. Can any one tell me what's causing this and if it's something I need to be concerned about.

Comment: Make sure file/directory permissions allow write access, fix it with `chmod`/`chown`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6419695/560287