# phpstorm IDE Could not save project:

Tags: ide, phpstorm

It's on the Ubuntu system.
I install the phpstorm IDE.
But when i use it do edit files and save them,it shows a error:

Could not save project:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/project/.idea/workspace.xml_**jb_bak_** (Permission denied).

If anyone know how to solve this problem, Please share your ways.

Thanks in advance

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733824/error-when-saving-in-web-storm-permission-denied

Comment: I just solve this problem.
chmod 777 -R  /home/project/.idea/

Comment: @Tony_Wang Thanks that seems to fix the issue. Should be `chmod -R 777 ...` though.

Comment: I guess you do know its because of permissions...nothing major

Comment: There was a SO moderator who went clinically insane when he saw the sheer number of answers and questions that suggested chmod 777 -R * poor fellow he's still lurking around out there :P

Answer (score 10):

[image]go to preferences, system settings -> then uncheck "use safe write" checkbox.

Comment: omg thank you so much, I have been looking for the solution to this for so long.

Comment: me too...I was grinding my teeth until now after changing permissions to write and then never having PHPStorm respect that.

Comment: This was a very annoying issue, tried giving full disk access, checked folder permissions, but this setting fixed it. Not sure what will be a disadvantage for not using the safe write option. At least I have git to rollback changes.