# Laravel The stream or file "/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, laravel-5.5, apache2.4

I'm running Laravel app on server (Ubuntu 16.04). I have an error

> The stream or file "/var/www/mydomain.com/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

I've already google my question. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45673457/6478676), but it wasn't helpful. I can't set 777 permission for storage (it's dangerous), as was suggested by many other answers I found.
Any other suggestions?

---

UPDATE:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

was helpful

Comment: Actually, in the answer, the user is saying to never set 777 to this directory, and suggesting to change the directory ownership.

Comment: So I did that and it wasn't helpful (as I mentioned in question)

Comment: What did you set the permissions to? You likely want something like `root:www 700` set for the logs directory (setting it for just the .log file may not be sufficient)

Comment: @ti7 I set permissions to root...

Comment: Sorry, it should obviously be `770` above; the group write permissions are required too. Please include at least the output of `ls` against the logs directory in your question to show its permissions and ownership.

Comment: @ti7 you wish I show laravel logs? (I hope I understood you correctly)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This commands were helpful:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```