# Laravel - The stream or file failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, apache, centos

I know this is a common problem on Laravel, but I think I'm having a different issue or else the settings aren't being updated.

I've looked at this [Laravel The stream or file "/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506193/laravel-the-stream-or-file-storage-logs-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened-fail) and this [How to set up File Permissions for Laravel 5 (and others)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others) but I still have this issue:

> The stream or file "/var/www/html/laravelwebapp/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

When I do this after going into the logs directory: `$ ls -l laravel.log`

I get this:

`-rwxrwxr-x 1 apache apache 0 Feb  8  2018 laravel.log`

I'm on CentOS which is why the group/user is `apache` not `www-data`. Yet even though the log is created by apache and apache is the owner and group, it can't open the stream? Does this mean Laravel is executing as another user? I'm a bit confused here, sorry :/

I've cleared the cache using artisan and also ran `composer dump-autload` but I can't seem to progress in my application because the log doesn't get written to.

**Update:** My php application is running as `nobody` when I run

```
echo exec('whoami');
```

Is this the problem and how do I fix that?

Comment: I believe it's being caused by SELinux.

Comment: @webmasterdro could you elaborate? :)

Comment: I'm not expert with SELinux, but give a shot and run this command: `setenforce 0` (temporally disable selinux). If you already added to the correct group and set permissions, but still see Permission denied, much likely is SELinux.

Comment: @webmasterdro Hmm okay, hopefully this can help another advise on a good long-term solution, as disabling it _seems_ to not be 100% correct practice - just guessing 

Comment: No, it isn't. That's why I said for you to just test, and if it works. And you're temporally disabling. :)

Comment: @webmasterdro when I run your command I get `setenforce: SELinux is disabled` and the log still isn't writable - same error

Comment: I even `reboot` and still nothing... *odd*.

Comment: Try give permission 0755 to /storage/logs and not to the log itself.

Comment: @webmasterdro already did that :( makes no difference... something else is up 

Comment: And to the __storage__? Also, the right command for SELinux (when enabled) is `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/laravelwebapp/storage`, and try that `chmod -R 0755 /var/www/html/laravelwebapp/storage`

Comment: Change your `storage` folder permissions from `755` to `777` and see if it works. If yes, your laravel app is executed as some another user.

Comment: Just a small test. Try to write file into `DocumentRoot` with the same script.

Comment: Check open_basedir value

Comment: @SiZE sorry, what do you mean check `open_basedir` value? if i do `ini_get('open_basedir')` in the root I get an empty string...

Comment: @SiZE also see my update, the scripts are running as `nobody`

Comment: @webmasterdro see my update, the scripts are running as `nobody`