# laravel - The stream or file "/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: linux, laravel, amazon-lightsail

My application is being deployed to AWS Lightsail(LAMP) and when I try to run `artisan migrate` it says:

```
The stream or file "/opt/bitnami/projects/app-name/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to o
pen stream: Permission denied
```

What I have tried so far is to allow access to storage via:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 storage
```

Also, I can only access my home page if I use `sudo chmod -R 777 storage` but not `sudo chmod -R 775 storage`. I am not sure why.

but it is still giving me the error. What seems to be this issue?

Comment: `sudo chmod -R ugo+rw storage`

Comment: @JEJ I cannot access my server if I use 775.

Comment: HINT::its not just about the number, it's about ownership

The first digit represents what the owner of the files can do

 The second digit is what members of the same group can do

The third digit is what anyone can do

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30639174/15648920 this may help you

Comment: Doesn't your command make it ```777```?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel The stream or file "/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506193/laravel-the-stream-or-file-storage-logs-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened-fail)

Comment: sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache

Answer (score 4):

This commands were helpful:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

also follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506193/laravel-the-stream-or-file-storage-logs-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened-fail)