# Permission Denied Error using Laravel & Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have two docker containers: Nginx and App.
The app container extends PHP-fpm and also has my Laravel Code.

In my `docker-compose.yml` I'm doing:

```
version: '2'
services:
    nginx:
        build:
            context: ./nginx
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        links:
            - app
    app:
        build:
            context: ./app
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```

In my Nginx Dockerfile i'm doing:

```
FROM nginx:latest
WORKDIR /var/www
ADD ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ADD . /var/www
EXPOSE 80
```

In my App Dockerfile I'm doing:

```
FROM php:7-fpm
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev mysql-client && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql
ADD . /var/www
```

After successfully running docker-compose up, I have the following error when I try localhost

> **The stream or file "/var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied**

From my understanding, the storage folder needs to writable by the webserver.
What should I be doing to resolve this?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Make your Dockerfile something as below -

```
FROM php:7-fpm
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev mysql-client && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql
ADD . /var/www
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

This makes directory `/var/www` owned by `www-data` which is the default user for `php-fpm`.

Since it is compiled with user `www-data`.

Ref-

https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/57b41cfc2d1e07acab2e60d59a0cb19d83056fc1/7.0/jessie/fpm/Dockerfile

Comment: This didn't work for me. Same error. Anyone has any idea.

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. This solution did not work for me either.

Comment: You can use the `--chown` flag on the `ADD` or `COPY` instruction to reduce your image size. Like `COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www`. In my case, the size of the image got reduced from 130MB to 100MB.

Comment: for me, I had to dive into the container itself using this command `docker exec -i -t (here is you container id) bash`

Comment: Found an article that explains the reason behind this. The problem with me - was that I am using Linux - https://github.com/shipping-docker/vessel-docs/blob/master/source/docs/linux-permissions.md

Answer (score 20):

I found similar problem and I fixed it by

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

chmod -R 755 /var/www/storage
```

Comment: I am getting: "cannot access '/var/www/storage': No such file or directory"

Comment: Try `chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/storage` or find a folder containing your Laravel app.

Answer (score 16):

When using bind mounts in Docker, the original permissions in the Docker host are preserved in the container. This enables us to set appropriate permissions on the Docker host, to be used inside the container.

First, you should find the `uid` and `gid` of the nginx, for example:

`docker-compose exec nginx id www-data`

The output of this command would be something like this:

`uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)`

Then, you should use these `uid` and `gid` to set permissions on Docker host, which will be used by the container too. So, run the following command on the Docker host:

`sudo chown -R 33:33 site`

Now everything must be working.

Comment: Thank you! By the way, you can perform this easily in your Dockerfile as you copy in the data with `COPY --chown=33:33 . .`. This preserves the ownership of the original files. (I've read that this will not work on Windows, however.)

Comment: maybe docker exec instead of docker-compose exec?

Answer (score 7):

You can do 3 things as I used/using

1. Grant 755 permission to `storage` folder (`sudo chmod 755 storage/ storage/*` )
2. [`RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www RUN chmod 755 /var/www`](https://github.com/shipping-docker/vessel/issues/1#issuecomment-335066855)
3. Move project folder to `/home` which is no need of special permission to write on that directory(**Personally Recommend this**) (In mine I have used `/home/projects/` and all of them placed there).

---

**Note:** If the project is in `/var/www/` then if you wrote file upload also you need permission to that folders too. this will avoid such error when you moved that to `/home`

Comment: Just an idea, but 777 is an unsafe permissions setting for web server folders. One suggestion is to instead use something like "ug+rw" (add READ and WRITE for USER (owner) and GROUP).

Comment: @SamuelBié ah just saw these commnts. typo  755

Answer (score 7):

I tried all of these, and it didn't work. My Laravel storage folder had access. But `/var/www/storage` still didn't had permission.

After reading multiple suggestions, with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411520/how-to-fix-error-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened) in particular. I did the following (kindly note that `php` is the name of my container image, and i linked my laravel project directly to `/var/www`):

1. From my docker, I ran `docker-compose exec php ls -al /var/www/storage`

   - I saw that only `root` had access but i need `www-data` to have access.
2. Then I ran `docker-compose exec php chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www/storage`

   - This gives `www-data` access to the storage folder
3. Then I ran `docker-compose exec php chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www/bootstrap/cache`

   - This gives `www-data` access to the bootstrap/cache folder

If you run item 1 again, `www-data` should have access, and your Laravel app should be fine.

Answer (score 7):

You need to create a user that matches the one on your machine (the one you created the project files with). So in the app Dockerfile, change your file like this:

```
FROM php:fpm

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev mysql-client

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Set the user
USER $user

# Copy your files
COPY . . # You can use "." as a destination since you already changed the workdir
```

Quick note: if you're using docker purely for local development, you don't to copy anything, just use bind mounts.

And in your docker-compose file, make the following changes:

```
app:
    build:
        args:
            user: essana3 # your username on your machine, you can get it by running echo $USER
            uid: 1000 # your uid which you can get by running id -u
        context: ./app
        dockerfile: Dockerfile # if your dockerfile is called Dockerfile, you don't need to add the dockerfile option
    volumes:
        - ./app:/var/www
```

BONUS:
You can use the dockerfile above to create utility containers in your docker-compose file to run artisan and composer commands:

```
  composer:
    build:
      args:
        user: essana3 # your username (echo $USER)
        uid: 1000 # your uid (id -u)
      context: ./app
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www
    entrypoint: ['composer']

  artisan:
    build:
      args:
        user: essana3 # your username (echo $USER)
        uid: 1000 # your uid (id -u)
      context: ./app
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www
    entrypoint: ['php', 'artisan']
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Docker Compose**

```
//Add this line:
user: 'www-data:www-data'
```

**Full Code**

```
services:
php:
    restart: always
    container_name: app-php
    user: 'www-data:www-data'
    build:
        context: ./docker/images/php
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    expose:
        - ${PHP_INTERNAL_PORT:-9000}
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/html
    networks:
        default:
            ipv4_address: 172.20.0.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what others have contributed, when using Laravel in Docker using Sail, the web server user is *sail*. One way to make sure what the exact username is to run:

```
var_dump(shell_exec('whoami'));
```

from a web page on the server. I had the same issue and granted permission to the *www-data* user. However, in my container, using Sail, the web server username was *sail*. Once I granted permissions and made *sail* the owner of the files, everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
docker exec -it <your container name> bash
chmod 777 storage/ -R
```

OR

```
docker exec -it <your container name> /bin/sh
chmod 777 storage/ -R
```

You can try it. It make your storage folder writeable