# Configuring laravel project with docker nginx error

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, docker-compose

i'm trying to set up a laravel project with mysql, phpmyadmin on docker. All the configurations seem to be good since `docker-compse up` starts all.
But when i try to acces to the default page i go that error on the log :

```
webserver     | 2020/02/03 09:02:36 [crit] 6#6: *4 stat() "/var/www/public/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
webserver     | 2020/02/03 09:02:36 [crit] 6#6: *4 stat() "/var/www/public/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
webserver     | 2020/02/03 09:02:36 [crit] 6#6: *4 stat() "/var/www/public/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

My dockerfile contains that:

```
# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www
# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www
# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www
# Change current user to www
USER www
```

and `ls -la` in the containers returns:

```
drwx------  2 www  www    4096 Oct 18 20:10 config
drwx------  5 www  www    4096 Oct 18 20:10 database
-rw-rw-r--  1 www  www    1358 Feb  3 08:48 docker-compose.yml
drwx------  2 www  www    4096 Oct 18 20:10 mysql
drwx------  3 www  www    4096 Oct 18 20:10 nginx
-rw-rw-r--  1 www  www    1125 Oct 18 20:10 package.json
drwx------  2 www  www    4096 Oct 18 20:10 php
-rw-rw-r--  1 www  www    1156 Oct 18 20:10 phpunit.xml
drwxrwxrwx  4 www  www    4096 Oct 18 20:10 public
drwx------  6 www  www    4096 Oct 18 20:10 resources
drwx------  2 www  www    4096 Oct 18 20:10 routes
-rw-rw-r--  1 www  www     563 Oct 18 20:10 server.php
```

I don't know what's wrong. i found this [Permission Denied Error using Laravel & Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48619445/permission-denied-error-using-laravel-docker) but i doesn't works.

Comment: Is the nginx user www?

Comment: Yes you can see in the docker file that i create the user www

Comment: Yes, but is the nginx configured to run as www user?

Comment: I don't realy understand what you mean

Comment: Try setting `chmod +X /var/www` (capital X) - will add search permission to directories for all users.

Comment: nginx.conf should have as user/group for the process as www and additionally php-fpm also user/group as www

Comment: @xyz suggestion worked thanks

Comment: Works, but it’s not really good solution

Comment: is there any solution? I am stuck on this problem for laravel 5.2 project and PHP version 5.6