# Laravel not executing apparently due to writing permissions

Tags: laravel, centos

This is the message I get:

> "Laravel.log could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission
>   denied"

I have tried using `chmod -R 777 /storage /bootstrap/cache` but that doesn't solve the problem. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your command is correct? Go inside your project and run `chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache`. I removed the slash at the beginning

Comment: yes buddy, the command is correct, it is without the slash at the beggining... But I see that after running this command storage and bootstrap/cache have all  permissions enabled for any user, however, it keeps ocurring the same error. I have exhausted almost all resources. What else could I do?

Comment: Try running `sudo chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache`. Or can you try running 'ls -l' and tell me what is the permission of `storage` folder.

Comment: This might help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411520/how-to-fix-error-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened)

Comment: Is there any Laravel.log in that location, my co-developer accidentallly deleted once.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, go to the project's root directory:

`chmod -R o+w storage
chmod -R o+w bootstrap`