# i need help in laravel 5.4 permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-5.4

[image]

it gives me this error when i put laravel on apache server

The stream or file "/var/www/app/storage/logs/laravel-2019-01-02.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

i have tried everything i set permission to 777 and set owner to root and i try permission 775 also didnot work can any one help me with this...?

> note: i am working on apache server on CentOS7

Comment: What exactly did you change the permissions and ownership of?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45673457. Hope it helps out.

Comment: Its a permission related error. Simply ensure that all the folders in the `storage` have the necessary permission (write & execute). Try `sudo chmod 777 storage/*/**`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Error: laravel.log could not be opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411520/how-to-fix-error-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened)

Comment: Please include code as [minimal, complete and verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of screenshots

Comment: didnot solve the problem i tried all these

Answer (score 0):

It's a permission issue:

Just Open Your CMD -> Go to your project folder -> Run the following command:

```
sudo chmod 777 storage/
```

Comment: i am on CentOS 7 and i have install apache server on it all direction command is already 777

Comment: Can you please enter into storage folder-> run ls -l command-> post its output here

Comment: and the onwership is  root:apache

Comment: this is the output of ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-x. 3 root apache   38 Dec  8 01:44 app
drwxrwxr-x. 6 root apache   81 Dec  8 01:44 framework
drwxrwxr-x. 2 root apache 4096 Dec 27 05:07 logs

Comment: That's actually weird...we get similar error whenever there is a permission issue. Still, I would request you to checkout this:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/23411520/9138047

Answer (score 0):

i fix it...
after using this command i still didnot know what is the reason
1.cd /var/www/html
2.setenforce 0
3.service httpd restart