# how to view adminlte template without php artisan serve

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu, permission-denied

I have my project created with adminlte template, when i deploy my project i tried it to run without php artisan serve command but i failed i tried this options but all of my design gone away and nothing work as it was before,

This is the error a got when I wrote localhost/akyo/public

The stream or file `

> "/opt/lampp/htdocs/akyo/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened:
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied`

I tried the following options

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage
sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R 777 app/storage
```

Any one with a way how to fix this

Comment: Which **exact** permission is set for the log files? Don't guess, check and post them

Comment: the permission in log file is 777

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411520/how-to-fix-error-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Error: laravel.log could not be opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411520/how-to-fix-error-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened)

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo chmod -R 777 storage/`