# laravel-2019-06-24.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, macos, sudo

I tried everything but not getting any solution. I am trying to make a project in laravel. I created the migration file but after writing php artisan migrate. I am getting the following error.

Here is Error pic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNN3X.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably get a Laravel error just before this one and the right on the error file is for apache. And for this error the right for the file should be for the user interface.

Here are command to set up special permission on all cache and storage directories.

```
$ sudo chown -R `whoami`:`whoami` /var/www/[site_name]
$ sudo chmod 775 -R /var/www/[site_name]
$ cd /var/www/[site_name]
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX storage bootstrap/cache
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx storage/ bootstrap/cache/`
```

`www-data` is your apache or ngix user which runs webservice

Comment: Not able to set read and write permission, it says, permission denied

Comment: I edited my post with commands I usually do when starting a new Laravel Project on my dev VM.

Comment: let me try, btw i have a mac operating system with Xampp

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the `storage` directory permission (as you have tried). It seems you have entered incorrect password.

Comment: i am entring Right password but still getting same error

Answer (score -1):

First, try the below commands and then run the artisan command again.

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan config:cache 

php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Please check that file exists in the location.

Comment: you will check link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411520/how-to-fix-error-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened