# How to setup XDebug with VSCode on Ubuntu on a Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm doing a simple laravel project and I have some code to debug but I can't make the debugging on VSCode work.

I'm on `Ubuntu 19.10`. I'm using `VSCode` insiders and Firefox with the XDebug extension. I followed the guide on `xdebug.org/wizard` but it didn't work.

Here is my xdebug configuration in my php.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Here is my launch.json

```
"name": "Listen for XDebug",
"type": "php",
"request": "launch",
"port": 9000
```

And my php -v

```sh
$ php -v
PHP 7.3.11-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 (cli) (built: Oct 24 2019 11:38:49) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.11, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.11-0ubuntu0.19.10.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.8.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans
```

I expect to be able to debug my `laravel` code but when I put a breakpoint in my code, it doesn't work. I am able to catch breakpoints that are in regular php files though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was using the command

```sh
php artisan serv
```

and accessing my server through `127.0.0.1:8000` and that was causing the isue.

You need to put the project in the `/var/www/html/` folder and then access it through `127.0.0.1/yourApp/public/`

You might need to add the files `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` to the webserver user: [How to fix Error: laravel.log could not be opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411520/how-to-fix-error-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened)