# PHP shell_exec() No output when specifying directory

Tags: php

It's working when i move the file to app current directory

```
$cmd = 'grep "Finished" sync.log | tail -n1;';
$exe = shell_exec($cmd);
error_log($exe);
```

Output:

```
I, [2020-01-27]  INFO -- : Finished
```

but when i try to specified the direcotry, it doesn't work

```
$cmd = 'grep "Finished" /var/log/sync.log | tail -n1;';
$exe = shell_exec($cmd);
error_log($exe);
```

**Edit**
Found this
https://www.linode.com/community/questions/18703/getting-error-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied
[How to fix Error: laravel.log could not be opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411520/how-to-fix-error-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened)

Then

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/log/sync.log"
restorecon -rv /var/log/
```

Comment: File exists, but no "Finished" log in `/var/log/sync.log`. Can you show your log?

Comment: sorry but i cant show you my logs, but they are just the same.
i only add specific path "/var/log" in the code

Comment: Missing permissions?

Answer (score 0):

can you specify the exact error you are getting, because I tried your code and its working fine.

Otherwise you can try with a system command as given below -

```
<?php
    system('grep "Finished" /var/log/sync.log | tail -n1;');
?>
```