# How to fix Error: laravel.log could not be opened Permission denied?

Tags: laravel, permissions

I'm pretty new at laravel,Actually when i create this command php artisan migration so i face this error how can i resolve this issue thanks.

**Error**

> UnexpectedValueException  : The stream or file 
>       "/home/zubair/htdocs/project/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open 
>       stream: Permission denied

Comment: How did you serve your Laravel app? Laravel built-in server? Nginx? Apache? or something else

Comment: I am using Apache server  on linux os.

Comment: I think the problem is the apache is using `www-data` user and you are using your own user. You need to change the user that apache is using to serve the app in apache configurations to be the same as the user you are running a command with.

Comment: It's duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45673457/10990444) . This answer will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the command with `sudo` or `chmod -R 755` some of the project's folders, you'll have it working.

`sudo chmod -R 755 storage bootstrap/cache`

Changing entire project folder's permission is probably not a good idea as your project becomes accessible to any user/script which kind of defeats the purpose of securing it behind root.

Comment: Why sudo? Just chmod problem

Answer (score 0):

change a permission of storage folder

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/your-project/storage
```

for more info check this link [install laravel in apache](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-for-apache/)

Comment: `chmod -R 755 storage bootstrap/cache` --> https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/pull/281/files