# Why saving image with spatie/image I got error?

Tags: laravel, laravel-storage

On Laravel 10 site using spatie/image I read file from storage path and making some modifications. I want to save it under other storage path, but I got error when try to save image under storage path

```
    $this->destPath = '/_wwwroot/lar/NewsPublisher/storage/app/public/photos/RESULTS/RESULT.png';
    // raise error: Unable to create a directory at /storage/app/public/photos.
```

I tried to write under public/storage subdirectory :

```
    $this->destPath = '/_wwwroot/lar/NewsPublisher/public/storage/photos/RESULTS/RESULT.png';
    //  raise error: Unable to create a directory at /storage/app/public/photos.
```

When I try to debug imagePathRef object

```
dd($this->imagePathRef);
```

It shows  :

```
Spatie\Image\Image^ {#1083
  #manipulations: Spatie\Image\Manipulations^ {#1084
    #manipulationSequence: Spatie\Image\ManipulationSequence^ {#1085
      #groups: array:1 [
        0 => array:3 [
          "width" => "400"
          "height" => "340"
          "border" => "10,#ff0c75,overlay"
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
  #imageDriver: "gd"
  #temporaryDirectory: null
  #optimizerChain: null
  #pathToImage: "/storage/app/public/photos/KdRLx9YQ6gNsMtqg27fdXjvYqaPJnsSz15PXIaqs.jpg"
```

With valid pathToImage image I provided

I pass a valid directory path :

```
/_wwwroot/lar/NewsPublisher/public/storage/photos/RESULTS$ ls -la
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 feb 28 10:45 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 feb 29 16:59 ..
```

So I excluded invalid path passed.

What is wrong ?

```
 "spatie/image": "^2.2.7",
 "laravel/framework": "^10.45.1",
```

Comment: `Unable to create a directory` Is this not a permission issue?

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth that is not a permission issue, 
you would need to create the directory where you are saving the image beforehand. Laravels File Storage does that automatically but looks like this package does not do it. So you will need to create one before trying to save it.

Comment: @AnujShrestha Pretty sure you can still have permission issue especially if your OS does not allow laravel(or www-data) to create files and folders. SO questions like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60124407 and hundreds of others says so.

Comment: You might have 775/777 there but owner is root. Change that to www-data(?) or something that allows laravel to create files and folders inside storage directory. it might be www-data or other user/groups depending on OS and server(apache or nginx)

Comment: If it is permission issue then the error will let you know that but in OP case the issue is the directory not found, that's how actually it works we need to have directory before trying to save a file in it, it is just laravel's `Storage` does that for you automatically