# There is no existing directory at Permission denied laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I hosted my project laravel before host i do php artisan optimize:clear php artisan cache:clear php artisan config:cache php artisan config:clear and when i go in /public  i see this error : There is no existing directory at "/home/myusername/Documents/2020.10.07/storage/logs" and it could not be created: Permission denied

How i can resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Error: laravel.log could not be opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411520/how-to-fix-error-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened) Just DONT use the 777 answer, thats garbage, use the 755 one

Comment: i need to do sudo chmod -R 755 storage
sudo chmod -R 755 bootstrap/cache ?

Comment: do it on that and the storage folder but yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try 
`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER storage` 
`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER bootstrap` 
Do it in the root of your laravel folder. 
Sorry i don't have enough reputation to answer them in the comments