# Laravel 7 XAMPP Mac OS: The stream or file "../storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened. Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, macos, xampp

Yes I know this question has been asked several times but I couldn't find 100% working solution yet. I have installed XAMPP from [https://www.apachefriends.org](https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/7.2.34/xampp-osx-7.2.34-0-installer.dmg) and then I installed Laravel 7 using composer command `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^7.0 blog`

Command "php artisan serve" successfully runs the project. BUT if I open the same project from URL "http://localhost/blog/public/" I get the error:

> The stream or file
> "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/blog/storage/logs/laravel.log"
> could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission
> denied

I cannot set folder permission to 777 because not a good approach. The permission is already "read&write". I have been following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411520/how-to-fix-error-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened) thread.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about using 777 permissions on a personal development machine.

Comment: You could try `sudo php artisan serve` instead.

Comment: chmod -R 755 is recommended in your thread provided

Comment: @miken32 No bro I just want to open the from url "http://localhost/blog/public/"

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data bootstrap/cache
```

and then

```
chmod -R 775 storage
chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
```

and if it won't work, try changing the 'www-data' group into '_www'.