# File's permission not changed on Debian Buster docker-compose project while in Ubuntu22.04 does

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, debian-buster, ubuntu-22.04

Hi I wanted to ask about something strange happened to me....

I was dockerizing a laravel app in a Lamp stack trough a digitalocean tutorial.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose

Basically when I do all the passages on a debian buster desktop, I got permission denied error, while if I do it on ubuntu 22.04 desktop I got no problems (tried on my dual boot laptop too and got absolutely no problem).

Here is the **error**:

*The stream or file "/var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied*

I still don't understand why, because the error it's not in docker-compose yml or Dockerfile, probably how debian manage the permissions of the files.
Thanks for any suggestions.

In case anyone wondering this is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1.0-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && install-php-extensions mbstring pdo_mysql zip exif pcntl gd

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    libzip-dev \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
#RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
#RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
#RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

#RUN php artisan key:generate

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY --chown=1000:1000 . /var/www


# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: the dockerfile is this :

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73138194/15186994

Answer (score 0):

This must be added to dockerfile. web server access to root folder and  755  to storage folder

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

chmod -R 755 /var/www/storage
```

Comment: Unluckily it didn't work, because the command --chown should do beforehand the work. Btw i added the dockerfile so you can see it. Thank you.