# Missing fields error when making a post request in Laravel

Tags: laravel, guzzle, tiktok-api

I am making a post request to the tiktok API, entering the 3 parameters that are requested, but when I carry out the request, it shows me the following: "Required fields are missing: app_id is required.", I attach an image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOuEU.png)

but when performing the same procedure in postman if I have a positive response.

here is my code:

my route:

```
Route::get('callback-tiktok', [AuthsController::class, 'SocialAuth']);
```

my controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;

class AuthsController extends Controller
{

    public function SocialAuth(Request $request)
    {
        $a = $request->input('auth_code');
        // create a guzzle client object here
        $client = new Client();
        $respuesta = $this->client->request(
            'POST',
            'https://business-api.tiktok.com/open_api/v1.3/oauth2/access_token/',
            [
                'form_params' => [
                    'app_id' => '7112335319877287937',
                    'secret' => '18f52730856f43ed821187bfa9283794ca360ef1',
                    'auth_code' => $a
                ],
                'headers'  =>  [
                    'Content-Type'      =>  'application /json'
                ],
            ]
        );
        return response()->json($respuesta->getBody()->getContents());
    }
}
```

When compiling I get the following:

The stream or file "/home/epgutp/tiktok/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/home/epgutp/tiktok/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/home/epgutp/tiktok/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/home/epgutp/tiktok/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/home/epgutp/tiktok/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/home/epgutp/tiktok/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file....

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Post it as plain or formatted text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you made some couple of errors, try this:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthsController extends Controller
{
    public function SocialAuth(Request $request)
    {
        $a = $request->input('auth_code');
        // create a guzzle client object here
        $client = new Client();
        $respuesta = $this->client->request('POST', 
              'https://business-api.tiktok.com/open_api/v1.3/oauth2/access_token/',
             [
              'form_params' => [
                'app_id' => '711233531987728793',
                'secret' => '18f52730856f43ed821187bfa9283794ca360ef',
                'auth_code' => $a
              ], 
              'headers'  =>  [
                'Content-Type'      =>  'application /json'
              ],
          ]);
         return response()->json($respuesta->getBody()->getContents());
        
    }

}
```

Applying this solution gives me the following error:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the support, I edited the question by adding the CURL code provided by the tiktok documentation regarding authorization, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Well, the next is to troubleshoot the authentication as i said in the comment. Like remove the `secret` and `auth_code` and put it in the `headers`. or better still, paste the `tiktok` url here in the comment and let me check it out.

Comment: Okay, i guess the issue is the `dd($cuerpo)`, try return the variable @Julio

Comment: Here is the url of the tiktok documentation, specifically the request we are talking about: 
 https://ads.tiktok.com/marketing_api/docs?id=1739965703387137

Comment: putting the auth code and secret in the header, I get the following error: "request body has an error: header Content-Type has unexpected value "application /json""

Comment: I've checked the url and sees that it's normal to pass it, but i think the `dd();` thats causing your issue. check the answer modification @Julio

Comment: I have made the changes to the modified answer, I already edited the question with your changes (you could review it) and the problem that I get.

Comment: then search for the error online. check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411520/how-to-fix-error-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened

Comment: I was able to find a solution to my problem, thank you very much for the support :D.

Comment: I still can't cast a vote, I need more reputation he tells me :(

Comment: @Julio you can cast vote now, your answer is helpful to the community

Comment: Ready and vote, if you have time and you can help me with this question I would appreciate it :D....I want to store a data of the response of this request in mysql here expand the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74608566/how-to-save-data-from-a-request-to-mysql-in-laravel

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe this can help someone, solution to my question:

In this case use the Http facade:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class AuthsController extends Controller
{
    

    public function SocialAuth(Request $request)
    {

        $a = $request->input('auth_code');

        // URL
        $apiURL = 'https://business-api.tiktok.com/open_api/v1.3/oauth2/access_token/';

        // POST Data
        $postInput = [
            'app_id' => '7112335319877287',
            'secret' => '18f52730856f43ed821187bfa9283794ca360',
            'auth_code' => $a
        ];

        // Headers
        $headers = [
            //...
        ];

        $response = Http::withHeaders($headers)->post($apiURL, $postInput);

        $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
        $responseBody = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

        echo $statusCode;  // status code

        dd($responseBody); // body response


    }
}
```

Response to my request:

```
^ array:4 [▼
  "code" => 0
  "message" => "OK"
  "request_id" => "202211281314430102451411010AF4A"
  "data" => array:3 [▼
    "access_token" => "fbcaa610339b7aeb39eabf29346d06a4e7fe9"
    "advertiser_ids" => array:1 [▶]
    "scope" => array:18 [▶]
  ]
]
```