# Apache set up mac os yosemite

Tags: apache, localhost, localserver

I am trying to get Apache to run on my yosemite machine, but when i try to access localhost i get https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzZzB.png.

I ran an apache configtest and got the following

`Angus-Mac:mysql root# apachectl configtest
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Angus-Mac.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK`

What am i getting wrong? any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your httpd.conf and /etc/hosts file?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vpCi1ugs - httpd.conf
http://pastebin.com/k2ZUuqx1 - hosts

Comment: Also please paste the permission you have on the directory? ls -l /Library/WebServer/Documents. and also paste the error_log. Thanks!

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Ek3lYuL.png
how do i get the error log?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name for MacBook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559201/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name-for-macboo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncommenting the `ServerName` and changing it to the domain name solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

change the group permissions on that folder to _www

```
sudo chgrp -R _www /Library/WebServer/Documents (all web content is now group _www)
chmod -R go-rwx /Library/WebServer/Documents (nobody other than owner can access web content)
chmod -R g+rx /Library/WebServer/Documents (all web content is now readable/executable/enterable by _www)
```

then restart apache 
It seems your user in httpd.conf is different that the one on the web directory

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6419695/1493954)

Please uncomment the ServerName in line 212 (httpd.conf) and change the domain www.example.com to your domain.
Restart apache

Comment: it says there is no such filler directory

Comment: Please run it again with your directory path.

Comment: now it says safari can't connect to localhost and it went back to forbidden

Comment: can you please share the error log from /var/log/apache2/error_log?

Comment: please change in httpd.conf: <IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule> to <IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule> and delete logs and restart apache. send me the error log again if you still face the same problem.

Comment: please delete the log and restart, its hard to figure along all those lines what is going on. after you restart please paste the log here again. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66256/discussion-between-angus-and-liorsolomon).