# Prestashop on mamp for mac “Recursive write permissions” error

Tags: macos, permissions, prestashop, mamp

I am trying to install Prestashop 1.6.14 on Mamp 3.0.7.2 for OS X 10.10.3

I got these error:

> Oops! Please correct the item(s) below, and then click "Refresh information" to test the compatibility of your new system.

```
Permissions on files and folders
Recursive write permissions for Apache user on ~/config/
Recursive write permissions for Apache user on ~/cache/
Recursive write permissions for Apache user on ~/log/
Recursive write permissions for Apache user on ~/img/
Recursive write permissions for Apache user on ~/mails/
Recursive write permissions for Apache user on ~/modules/
Recursive write permissions for Apache user on ~/themes/default-bootstrap/lang/
Recursive write permissions for Apache user on ~/themes/default-bootstrap/pdf/lang/
Recursive write permissions for Apache user on ~/themes/default-bootstrap/cache/
Recursive write permissions for Apache user on ~/translations/
Recursive write permissions for Apache user on ~/upload/
Recursive write permissions for Apache user on ~/download/
```

I have tried to set chmod at 775 and 777 but the error persists.

On my Mac, I do not have the user apache.

> drwxrwxr-x@  10 vnt  staff       340 17 Apr 23:07 cache

How do I configure the permissions?

Comment: Did you set that permissions recursively?

Comment: The apache user on mamp is called `_www` not `apache` from what I understood
Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001881/correct-owner-group-permissions-for-apache-2-site-files-folders-under-mac-os-x

Comment: I have solved the problem. Edit the file  **/install/controllers/http/system.php** and change the owner in line 78 **$user = 'vnt';**