# Why is localhost different than opening files directly

Tags: html, xampp

Currently working on MAC Yosemite and trying to test out a website I'm developing on XAMPP (newest version) and Sublime Text. Just downloaded an image from the internet and saved into my htdocs file. When I submit index.html into my url for testing, that image is not displayed. However, when I open the same file like:

> file:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/index.html

the image is shown perfectly? Here's the code:

```
<form method="get" action="/search" id="search">
  <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Browse" />

</form>
#search input[type="text"] {
    background: url(search-white.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #fcfcfc;
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    color: #bebebe;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    }
```

Would it look different from testing it out in

> file:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/index.html

than localhost/index.html 
What is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set permissions so image is readable by webserver.

Comment: How Would I Do That Sir?

Comment: this should help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001881/correct-owner-group-permissions-for-apache-2-site-files-folders-under-mac-os-x

Comment: still waiting 1 min left ;)