# Magento2 Cache files 403 Forbidden?

Tags: magento, magento2

Notice that once new cache folder created, it will turn out to be 403 Forbidden. How do I solve this on Magento2?

If I ran this command, it will work for temporary till new cache folder created and it turn out to be 403 forbidden again.

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Please put solutions in an *answer post*, not in the question. Summarise the solution in your own words, don't just link.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue related to permissions, users and groups (as also pointed out in [this 3d](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51553/images-in-media-catalog-product-cache-are-created-as-rootroot-and-hence-give-4) about a similar problem).

The solution is to [set in your `httpd.conf` file the Apache user](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/forbidden-403-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-username-on-this-server/):

```
<IfModule unixd_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User Aerendir
Group staff
```

Other useful resources:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2412
- [Correct owner/group/permissions for Apache 2 site files/folders under Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001881/correct-owner-group-permissions-for-apache-2-site-files-folders-under-mac-os-x)

Answer (score -1):

Just run following command in Shell/terminal after cleaning cache.

```
chmod 777 -R var/
```