# Chrome won't display filesystem images

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, background-image

Problem: When I try to load the image as part of the web page, I get (blocked:other) as a response to the image request in the Chrome inspector (as opposed to 200 or 404). When I paste the image location into the address bar, it loads, so I know the path is correct. Same responses from Firefox.

Example path that loads directly in browser but not in web page/css: file:///Users/my-username/path-to-app/assets/images/give-them-beer/12-top-rated-ipas_1200.jpg

Example path that doesn't load anywhere (returns 404 in inspector): http://localhost/mysite.com/assets/images/give-them-beer/12-top-rated-ipas_1200.jpg

System info:

- I'm working on a localhost website (Mac, using MAMP + Apache).
- I'm using the latest version of Chrome.

Web site info:

- I am using CodeIgniter 3.x
- My assets directory is outside the application directory
- I am using the full filesystem path for the image.
- I am loading images as CSS background using inline styles

What I've investigated:

- I've tried localhost URLs and filesystem URLs
- .htaccess CSP options, though I can't find one that fixes the problem
- .htaccess XSS options, but again, I can't figure out how to get around it
- The MAMP permissions suggestions the comments. New permissions are:

  - Localhost dir: `drwxr-x---+  7 ME  _www  238 Sep 10 09:37 DOCUMENTDIRECTORY`
  - Website dir: `drwxrwx---+ 15 ME  _www  510 Sep 11 09:50 MYSITEDIRECTORY`

Comment: Please reply to your own question instead of adding a note to the original question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

You could try switching the setting in MAMP "Run Apache/MySQL server as user:" to run as your local user account rather than "www", if you haven't already.

Comment: Thank you for a new direction to look in! I've used the instructions here, http://ifmeister.com/mamp-file-permissions-for-a-local-development-environment/, but I don't have MAMP Pro and I can't figure out how to set the default user in MAMP. Without that last bit it didn't fix the issue, but I'm still working at it...

Comment: I subsequently followed the permissions instructions here,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001881/correct-owner-group-permissions-for-apache-2-site-files-folders-under-mac-os-x and restarted Apache. No dice with either file:/// or localhost approach. :(

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it to a CodeIgniter configuration issue. I needed to add the assets folder to the .htaccess rewrite rules, like this:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`