# Logs error in apache server , logs folder can't be accessible , why?

Tags: linux, macos, apache, httpd.conf, vhosts

I am using XAMP on mine MAC System (OS: macOS High Sierra) and I follow the steps: I have permissions issue but i can't understand why ..

1. I have default configuration on mine XAMP in `httpd.conf` file for :

```html
<IfModule unixd_module>
      User daemon
      Group daemon
  </IfModule>
```

2. I have a laravel project in mine `htdocs` directory:

   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sites have the 2 sites:

```html
drwxrwxr-x  5 daemon  daemon  160 Dec  2 07:11 beinstyle
drwxrwxr-x  5 daemon  daemon  160 Dec  2 07:10 conlineltd
```

In that sites directories i have logs directory:

```html
drwxrwxr-x   2 daemon  daemon   64 Nov 29 18:26 logs
```

3. I made the virtual hosts:

```html
httpd.conf configuration for:
Listen 80
Listen 8080

# Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf // included

httpd-vhosts.conf
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin conlineltd.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/sites/conlineltd/project/public"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ServerName conlineltd.com
    ServerAlias www.conlineltd.com
    ErrorLog "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/sites/conlineltd/logs/"
    CustomLog "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/sites/conlineltd/logs/" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin beinstyle.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/sites/beinstyle/project/public"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ServerName beinstyle.com
    ServerAlias www.beinstyle.com
    ErrorLog "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/sites/beinstyle/logs/"
    CustomLog "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/sites/beinstyle/logs/" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I run the following commands:

```
`sudo dseditgroup -o checkmember -m macbook daemon` after checking the command return yes!

 sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a macbook -t user daemon
```

Error logs from apache:

> > (21)Is a directory: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/sites/beinstyle/logs/.
> >     AH00015: Unable to open logs
> >
> > Mine system logged user is macbook do i need to add him to a daemon group ?

I am new to the permissions topic on linux systems and maybe i miss something simple here , Please need your help !!

Comment: If the user macbook aint part of group daemon that user does not have write access to the _logs_ folder.
_drwxrwxr-x_ indicates that the user daemon and users from same group has rwx, and other groups/users in the system has r-x, read and execute.

Comment: I added the macbook to group and checked if the user is there . The code above . But i still stuck with that problem .

Comment: If you, as the _macbook_ user `$ cd /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/sites/beinstyle/logs/` and try `$ touch test.txt`, what happens?

Comment: -rw-r--r--  1 macbook  daemon  0 Dec  3 00:34 file.txt
File was created i got this result!

Comment: What happens if you chmod the log directory to 777? `chmod 777 /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/sites/beinstyle/logs/`. Mind you, it might not be clever to keep it 777.

Comment: Yes i know and i don't want to do it ! I want to give the ownership only to apache! But i got the error above so ...

Comment: Are you sure it's the `macbook` user that runs the Apache daemon? Default seems to be _www, https://serverfault.com/questions/152175/apache-runs-as-which-user-group-under-os-x-10-6 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001881/correct-owner-group-permissions-for-apache-2-site-files-folders-under-mac-os-x

Comment: Yes i am talking about XAMP and not built in web server ..