# PHP 8 - Warning: Unknown: Failed to open stream

Tags: php, runtime-error

Consider:
I have a file called test.php. Here is the contents:

```
<?php 
    echo "Hello World"; 
?>
```

I have ensured my doc root has permissions as per [Correct owner/group/permissions for Apache 2 site files/folders under Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001881/correct-owner-group-permissions-for-apache-2-site-files-folders-under-mac-os-x)

When I try to run the above script on my MAMP stack I get this warning:

> Warning: Unknown: Failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in Unknown on line 0

Could someone shed some light on my error here please?

Edit: I have tried the ideas below - thank you to @Shozabjaveed - but these have not worked.

Comment: " in the end remove it

Comment: Sorry @Shozabjaveed - that was a typo in my question. My file does not contain that - I have checked.

Comment: did you check the folder permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure that the Apache service has read permissions.

```
chmod 755 test.php
```

or ran the recursive command to ensure that the Apache service has read permissions.if using MAC

```
sudo chmod -R 755 ~/foldername
```

Comment: The permissions in the folder and higher directories are read, write, execute for me, and read, execute for other parties.